# bootstrap-table: how to dynamically pull params required for ajaxRequest(params) call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have used bootstrap-table successfully to load AJAX data into a single table using the following call:

```
function ajaxRequest(params) {
    $.getJSON( 'ajax.php?action=doSomething' + $.param(params.data), {format: 'json'}).then(function (res) {
        params.success(res)
    });
}
```

But now I'd like to work with multiple tables, each with their own ID, which will be populated by an onClick event bound to a button. Can anyone tell me how I can get the **params** for any given table required by the function?

The HTML for each table is in the format:

```
<table id="table-{$id}" class="my-table" data-toggle="table"
                    data-search="false"
                    data-ajax="ajaxRequest"    
                    data-side-pagination="server"
                    data-pagination="true"> 
    <thead>
          <tr>
              <th data-field="field1" data-sortable="true">Field 1</th>
                  ...
          </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Thanks!